# Problems with an external HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, external-hdd

First of all, sorry for my english, but i really hope that someone could help me with my problem, here is it:

I tried to install Arch Linux in my external HDD, alongside with Ubuntu 20.04. The thing is that i made a mistake, when i was formating the drive to select a partition, i introduced the command "GPD". I am not sure what i done there, because my entire disk show itself like completely empty. So, i got scared, and i stopped instalation, and when i use a recovery tool from windows, i realize that all the data is still there. So, my question is this:

Is there any way to recovery the OS without making external recovery, and just reinstall the grub to recognize the parititions? Because literally, my ubuntu live cd, just see the disk as a blank disk, windows see a blank disk as well. Hope you could help me please.

Comment: Wow sorry about that.  We have all at one time made a mistake like that. If during your install you did select a full disk install and created a new GPT partition table then most likely there's no easy way to recover. A partition table only creates a way to organize partitions.  AFTER that you make partitions.  If you killed the install part way through that was not finished.  If you can "see" the data then I recommend a Ubuntu live USB or DVD.  Use that to look into the drive and copy all of the data to an external drive.  Then and only then add partitions. Then full reinstall.

Comment: Please explain exactly which drive/partition mistake was made on and what was on it.  You said used windows tools to see data, was partition a Windows OS or NTFS data partition.  Important to know to give best advice.

Comment: No, I use a program to see if I could try to recovery the data, but as soon as I saw that those program couldn't actually recovery data without a premium subscription, I uninstalled them.  My windows 10 is set as NTFS, but on my internal HDD. Ubuntu is the one who was set as ext4 on the external HDD.

Comment: Walttheboss:.    You mean that there's no other option than recovery and backup all data, and then dump away the system to reinstall it? Because I tried to recovery from an Ubuntu live usb, and it just don't see anything but a blank disk. I tried to reinstall the grub in the traditional way, but it appears like as long as the disk continues being a blank disk, Ubuntu won't be able to mount, or even recognize it as an actual OS, or even as an actual external drive. So that way was already tried, and it didn't work out.

Comment: Unless a better person can give better advice here is a link for Linux recovery tools.  Should read/research as much as possible before using for best results.  Might need extra hard drive to copy to.  https://linuxhint.com/top_data_recovery_tools_linux/

Comment: Thank you very much crip659, I really appreciate that you took your time to try help me. Thanks for the link, it seems like that there's no other options for me :-(. I am going to use the tool you have provided me, thanks a lot men.

Comment: Remember these tools should only be used after studying them for best results.  They are not point and click for new users.  This is why they say backups are your friend, too few of us use it.

Comment: I installed Kubuntu Live USB on top of a 4TB external drive with every black and white movie ever released PD on it. Tried every Free recovery tool I could find. Nothing would work. Finally recovered everything using EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard, a Windows tool.

Comment: Thank you very much C.S.Cameron, it worked out with the rest of the data.